# Use next item in the list within a condition in a for loop

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have the following loop which is parsing the outputs of a difflib comparison of 2 configuration files and, so far showing me the differences in file 2 (indicated with +) and the heading in the file that 
the difference falls under e.g. [server]

**code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import difflib
from difflib import Differ

conf = open('C:/Users/fitzs/Documents/Scripts/example_ISAM_conf_file.txt', 'r')
upconf = open('C:/Users/fitzs/Documents/Scripts/Updated_ISAM_conf_file.txt', 'r')

d = difflib.Differ()

diff = list(d.compare(conf.readlines(), upconf.readlines()))# creates a 'generator' list of diffs

delta = ''.join(diff).strip('# ') #converts the list to string


for x in diff:
    x = str(x).strip()
    if x.startswith('+'):
        print(x)
    elif x.startswith('['):
        print(x)
```

**Example Output:-**

```
    The above code is giving me the following example output so far.  

    [server]
    + # web-host-name = www.myhost.com
    + https-port = 1080
    + network-interface = 0.0.0.0
    [process-root-filter]
    [validate-headers]
    [interfaces]
    [header-names]
    [oauth]
    [tfim-cluster:oauth-cluster]
    [session]
    + preserve-inactivity-timeout = 330
    [session-http-headers]
```

what I'm trying to do is only print a heading (e.g [server] ) if the next element in the list begins with + thereby excluding the headers that have no deltas under them'

on other words for the line with the header to print 2 conditions must be met:
1.  the line must begin with [
2. the next line must begin with +

**for example:**

```
[server]
+ # web-host-name = www.myhost.com
+ https-port = 1080
+ network-interface = 0.0.0.0
[session]
+ preserve-inactivity-timeout = 330
```

To achieve this I've tried changing the above for loop to the following:

```
for x in range(0, len(diff)):
    stanza = diff[x+1]
    x = str(x).strip()
    if x.startswith('+'):
        print(x)
    elif x.startswith('[') and stanza.startswith('+'):
        print(x)
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fitzs/PycharmProjects/Pydiffer/Pydiffer.py", line 35, in <module>
    stanza = diff[x+1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks for the below advice, I've updated my code as follows and it now runs with no errors.  However the index seems to be getting returned in the loop rather than the actual line itself:-

my for loop now looks like:-

```
for x in range(0, (len(diff) - 1)):
    # print (diff)
    y = str(x)
    print (x) 
    z = diff[x+1]
    if y.startswith('+'):
        print(y)
    elif y.startswith('[') and z.startswith('+'): 
        print(y)
```

Comment: Try changing the range to `range(0, len(diff)-1)`.

Comment: Hi Vasilis.. Thanks I've amended my code as above and now runs without errors.  However, it looks like the index number is being retuned in my loop rather than the content of the line being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for error is when `x = len(diff), stanza = diff[x+1]` is out of index because `x+1` is equal to `(len(diff) +1)`. Please use `range(len(diff)-1)` or `range(0,len(diff)-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not go through your script but the error can be resolved be changing the for loop to the following

```
for x in range(0, (len(diff)-1):
```

You are getting that error because in `stanze=diff[x+1]` you are requesting an element wich is len(diff)+1, which does not exist.